# ImportError: libopencv_ml.so.4.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, opencv

I have multiple version of opencv in different conda environments
But for a while now whenever I try to run or debug any python file in pycharm it give this error

`ImportError: libopencv_ml.so.4.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
It works when I run from console

I believe this issue started after I installed an openvino update a few weeks ago